# How to make all the tab indentation to align together in Vim

Tags: vim

I saw the following code in the DataMapper documentation, the `Serial`, `String`.. all align together, Can I do the same thing in Vim?

```
class Post
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,         Serial    # An auto-increment integer key
  property :title,      String    # A varchar type string, for short strings
  property :body,       Text      # A text block, for longer string data.
  property :created_at, DateTime  # A DateTime, for any date you might like.
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `Tabularize.vim` plugin. Run this command:

```
:Tabularize /:\w\+,\|#/
```

---

What you need is a pattern to match the delimiters.

- `:\w\+,` will match `:id,`, `:title,`, ...
- `#` will match the comment sign